# Multicolumn is only using the width of the first column

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I am using the `multicolumn` command to cover four columns in my table, but for some reason the text within the column is wrapping within a single column width leaving the remainder of the column empty. I can see that the column is still the width I'd like, since the right strut of the cell is where it is supposed to be. I think it may be related to my use of the `tabularx` environment, but I need it to allow the table to shift to fit the different possible cell values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Meeting Date:} & 2009/08/01 & \textbf{Type:} & Party & \textbf{Today's date:} & 2014/01/14 \bigstrut \tabularnewline 
\hline
\textbf{Meeting Location:} & \multicolumn{4}{X|}{This is the long string of text that I would like to break but when it has filled four columns rather than one.} & \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Current Weather:} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{Cloudy and sunny} \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Sector:} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{Food and Produce} \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tabularx` documentation clearly states:

> Do not use `\multicolumn` entries which cross any `X` column.

You can substitute your

```
\multicolumn{4}{X|}{This is the long string...}
```

with

```
\multicolumn{4}{p{4in}|}{This is the long string...}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Meeting Date:} & 2009/08/01 & \textbf{Type:} & Party & \textbf{Today's date:} & 2014/01/14 \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Meeting Location:} & \multicolumn{4}{p{4in}|}{This is the long string of text that I would like to break but when it has filled four columns rather than one.} & \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Current Weather:} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{Cloudy and sunny} \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Sector:} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{Food and Produce} \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]